# I can't open sh files with LXTerminal

Tags: server, lubuntu, minecraft

I'm fairly new to lubuntu and had planned to run my mine craft server on it. The problem is that I can not run sh files. The window just flashes when I run with

> lxterminal - command" /home/[username]/[server folder]/craftbukkit.sh

Help!

Comment: Does the script have a #!/bin/bash as the first line?

Answer (score 3):

Go to that folder and make it executable:

```
chmod -c +x craftbukkit.sh
```

Then execute it as:

```
bash craftbukkit.sh
```

or

```
./craftbukkit.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about lxterminal but to run most shell scripts from a terminal window you would

```
sh ./shellscript.sh
```

or

```
chmod +x ./shellscript.sh
./shellscript.sh
```